# SESSION working fine on server but not maintained through out

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I am using PHP to make a Website for 3 kinds of users as Head, Main, Normal.
So, i created a page for logging which will check for the credentials and move the sessions to the corresponding folder. I have structure like

```
main //folder
head //folder
normal //folder
index.php
```

this index.php will check user type and navigate to index page of the corresponding folder.

It is working fine on localhost. But on server it is redirecting properly to the folder but there the sessions are empty so a blank page comes.

i did

```
DEFINE('COOKIE_BASE_DOMAIN_NAME', '.domain.com');
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', COOKIE_BASE_DOMAIN_NAME);
session_start();
```

on every page but still the problem is same. I checked session path so i printed phpinfo and i got

```
session
Session Support     enabled
Registered save handlers    files user sqlite
Registered serializer handlers  php php_binary wddx

Directive   Local Value Master Value
session.auto_start  Off Off
session.bug_compat_42   Off Off
session.bug_compat_warn On  On
session.cache_expire    180 180
session.cache_limiter   nocache nocache
session.cookie_domain   no value    no value
session.cookie_httponly Off Off
session.cookie_lifetime 0   0
session.cookie_path /   /
session.cookie_secure   Off Off
session.entropy_file    no value    no value
session.entropy_length  0   0
session.gc_divisor  100 100
session.gc_maxlifetime  1440    1440
session.gc_probability  1   1
session.hash_bits_per_character 4   4
session.hash_function   0   0
session.name    PHPSESSID   PHPSESSID
session.referer_check   no value    no value
session.save_handler    files   files
session.save_path   /var/php_sessions   /var/php_sessions
session.serialize_handler   php php
session.use_cookies On  On
session.use_only_cookies    Off Off
session.use_trans_sid   1   1
```

any idea what i am missing or how it should be done ? sessions are creating because it navigates to other page and there is a condition that after session creation it should navigate only. But on second page session array is null. Ideas will be highly appreciated.

Comment: do you call `session_start()` on subsequent pages?

Comment: Do you get new session ID's on sub pages or are the identical `echo session_id();`?

Comment: both are the same from main index page to the page after loggin and redirection 
5253fabb6d6138db2537a4e37325f2a6 
5253fabb6d6138db2537a4e37325f2a6

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks like cookies are not working correctly (or blocked or whatever). If cookies are not working, PHP will add the session ID to the end of the URL in the query string (as PHPSESSID).

If you redirect using header(), the session ID won't be appended automatically and the session ID is lost.

Could you try this:

```
header("Location: folder/index.php?" . SID);
exit();
```

Comment: Using query string to transfer SID is insecure and not recommended. And the session will be lost on the next click anyway. And as the OP confirmed in the comments, the session identifier gets transferred all right

Comment: Yes, but it might give an idea as to what is causing it. It looks like the SID is not transferred alright, because the OP checks the existence of a session before he redirects and after redirecting, there's no session left.

Comment: mySQL based sessions are to be preferred in every case (when file based sessions fail). Besides it seems the OP not tried to change the save path to any location accessible via FTP. You may say "it works" - but how ... this solution is just a good example of an absolute anti-pattern. Would vote it down for sure if I would have just 1 point more reputation :)

Answer (score 0):

You may check for directory /var/php_sessions ... if permissions are OK and if files are created there.

Beside that, just start a new session, if none exists & disable cookie timeout (until the browser disconnects):

```
if(!$_SESSION){
   session_set_cookie_params(0);
   session_start();
}
```

DEBUG:

For debug purposes it's helpful to change the path to something accessible, e.g.:

```
ini_set('session.save_path','/home/someuser/public_html/sessions/');
```

In a productive environment it has to outside of the web-root in every case, just see comment below.

If all not helps, try something like this on subsequent pages (your phpinfo is missing relevant info, so it's just a guess):

```
$_SESSION[SID]['page']
```

HINT:

Call session_destroy() or delete the PHPSESSID cookie in your browser when you've changed something ...

Comment: thanks for the answer. But nothing happened and i don't have access to /var folder. so how can i do it?

Comment: If not cookies then what do you recommend?

Comment: @Astha: you may define another session.save_path location - preferably one level above the web-root (has to be inaccessible over HTTP in every case). If you can't go up - just set the webroot one level deeper, for example: /public_html/sessions/ and /public_html/htdocs ... ini_set('session.save_path','/public_html/sessions/'); Changing the path to some path which you can access might also be helpful to find out what's going wrong...

Comment: PHP sessions are cookie based, and the most secure sessions use cookies, not the horrible transid nonsense that polluted URL's in output HTML.  Not having cookies turned on is a non issue for someone who is using sessions - it's a given that it's a requirement for using the site.

Comment: Indeed, there's a cookie called PHPSESSID - with expiry: At end of session ... that 'remember me' function is quite the same - just with another expiry date. In case client doesn't support cookies - the SID still can be hidden in ajax-calls - instead of displaying it in the browser's address-bar (so it won't be saved into be bookmarks, for example). I code mainly AJAX apps, where the problem is that the session need to be timely stretched by accessing any blank page once in a while in order to keep the session alive - just ping/pong.